# Help understanding a proof for "if a prime number $p$ divides $ab$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

I am a first semester student of mathematics and I don't really understand the proof for the proposition written in the title of this post.
The proof says, that assumed $p \not | \: a$
implies that $$1 = pu+av, \qquad \text{for some $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$.}$$
Therefore $$b = bpu+abv, \text{ which is divisible by p}$$ Hence proved. 
 My problem: Why is the last equation necessarily divisible by $p$? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean 1 = pu+av, for some u,v. Not for some a,b.

Comment: another way you could argue is using prime decomposition from the fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Comment: Extremely minor point: People usually say "divisible" rather than "dividable".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are given (as a hypothesis) that $p$ divides $ab$; and so $p$ divides $abv$. Clearly also $p$ divides $bpu$. So $p$ must divide $b=bpu+abv$.

Comment: Thank you. I hate myself for not seeing that fact xD